# PHP output not updating

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

#### THE CODE

Hi everyone. I've got this code in my page.php file (using wordpress, but this question is not related to worpdress since I don't think it's its fault)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <?php if(!is_front_page()) : ?>
        <!-- the "lazy block" -->
        <!-- this block doesn't update -->
        <div class='page-title'> 
            <div class='container'>
                <h1> <?php echo strtoupper($pagename); ?> </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="hidden-xs col-md-3 col-md-push-1">
                <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

#### THE PROBLEM

Previously the outer element of the lazy block (see comments) had "page-header" as class, but since that class name is already used by bootstrap and since its behaviour is completely different from the one that I aim to achieve, I switched to the current one (page-title). 
 The problem is: doesn't matter what I write in the lazy block: nothing changes. I'm still getting a page-header... But, the rest of the code updates like a charm.

#### MY ATTEMPTS

I've already tried to clear my browser cache (and even history whilst trying), but nothing. Tried to yell at the monitor, but nothing. Tried to load it from my phone, but still nothing. Changed sintax (from an echo to an if block), but, well, do I need to repeat? 
 Any help would be apprecieted.

#### THE SOLUTION

Always make sure that you are modifying the right file AND that there aren't repetitions of code among your template files... It can become tricky to spot the error when you forget how you had organized your theme.

Comment: This happens to me sometmes. What I do is, in Chrome, enter the source code view and f5 from there, so that I see that it actually updates the code. Weird, but works.

Comment: I'm trying. Doesn't work

Comment: Are you testing locally? Wamp? Linux? Windows? Are you sure you're updating the file that is in the server root? (Yes I know, it sound weird but sometimes it happens)

Comment: I'm online on altervista. Think it's lamp, but yeah, with wordpress becomes wamp. Fairly sure

Comment: It's probably a server issue then. Ask them what's going on? (Probably a cache issue)

Comment: I'll try to open a parallel thread on their forums. Thanks for the hint. Yes, just need to set up docker

Comment: I would test the code locally (Installl duplicator plugin and make a backup and copy it to your local webserver. If you don't have any install WAMP if you're using Windows). If that works then you know it's a server issue.

Comment: Nice solution >_>